# Difference between equality checking inside 'if condition' vs 'console.log'

Tags: javascript

I was trying out a code snippet and the results are different for an empty array check inside a console.log statement and in a conditional statement.
Help/Thoughts on why this is different?
Thanks in advance!

```js
//Output: true
if([]) {
  console.log(true)
} else{
  console.log(false)
}

//Output: false
console.log([] == true)
```

Comment: `[]` equals to an array which is not not a false value like undefined or null etc that's why it returns true try it with a variable and you'll see, `[] == true` this tests whether the array is empty or not

Comment: Co**mparing** a value *with* a Boolean is different from co**nverting** a value *to* a Boolean.

Comment: [] is a truthy value, meaning it is considered true in the boolean context of if. Truthy values are all values that are not specified as falsy ("", 0, NaN, undefined, null, false). That is why `true` gets printed first.

When comparing, Javascript converts any non-boolean type into it's string representation first. If you call the toString method on an empty array, you get the empty string. So `console.log([] == true)` essentially becomes `console.log("" == true)`


https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive

Comment: @manonthemat: *"When comparing, Javascript converts any non-boolean type into it's string representation first."* That's not correct. E.g. numbers are not converted to strings. A correct statement would be: When comparing a primitive value with an object, the object is converted to a primitive value. When comparing a non-boolean value to a boolean value, the boolean value is converted to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be running into a known JavaScript quirk.

"[] is truthy, but not true"

The problem isn't where you are doing the evaluations, but rather that the two evaluations which seem identical are actually different.

See
https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs#-is-truthy-but-not-true

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that the if/else block, in part of its "truthful" test is checking if something exists (not just if it is true or not) -- wherein the straight console print is comparing the value of the empty array against a boolean (which would be false)

```js
let test = 'apple';
if( test ){
  console.log( 'if/else: ' + true );
}else{
  console.log( 'if/else: ' + false );
}

console.log( 'log: ' + ( test == true ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The two snippets are actually doing different things, hence the different results.

The first, with `[]` as the condition of the `if` statement, coerces the array to a Boolean value. (`if`, naturally enough, only works on Booleans, and JS will happily convert the given value if it isn't already Boolean.) This produces `true` - all objects in JS are "truthy", which includes all arrays.

For the second snippet, you are using the "loose equality" operator `==` - for which the JS specification provides a set of rules for how to convert the values into other types, eventually reaching a straightforward comparison between two values of the same type. You might want, or hope, that comparing a non-Boolean to `true` or `false` in this situation coerced the non-Boolean to Boolean - but this isn't what happens. What the specification says is that first the Boolean is coerced to number value - resulting in `1` for `true` (and `0` for `false`). So it reduces to `[] == 1` - which will go through a few more conversions before resulting in a `false` result.

The key point is that no conversion to Boolean happens in the second case. If you think this is stupid, you're probably right. This is a bit of a gotcha, and one of the reasons many guides tell you never to use `==` in JS. I don't actually agree with that advice in general (and hate linters telling me to always use `===` in any circumstances) - but you do have to be aware of some dangers. And using `==` to compare a value to `true` or `false` is something to *always* avoid.

Luckily, if you want to test if `x` is truthy or falsy, you have a very short and understandable way to do it - the one you used in the first snippet here: `if (x)`

Answer (score -1):

[edit] So my original answer was confusing as heck, and there are some incongruencies in the many answers you find on this subject all over the internet; so, let me try this again:

**Part 1: Why they are Different**

*if([])* and *if([] == true)* are not the same operation.  If you see the below example, you will get the same result when doing the same operation.

```
//Output: false
if([] == true) {
    console.log(true);
} else{
    console.log(false);
}

//Output: false
console.log([] == true);
```

**Part 2: Why it matters AKA: the confusing bits**

In JS, the following is a common expression used to see if an object/variable exists:

```
var foo = "Hello World";
if (foo) ...
```

From a design perspective, this test is not important to see if *foo* is equal to true or false, it is a test to see if the program can find the object or variable *foo*.  If it finds *foo*, then it executes the results in the "then" condition, otherwise you get the "else" condition.  So, in this case, it will  convert foo to either false for does not exist, or true for does exist.  So in this case the string is reduced to a boolean.

In contrast:

```
var foo = "Hello World";
if (foo == true) ...
```

Is typically trying to find out if the value of *foo* actually equals true.  In this case, you are comparing the value of foo "Hello World" to a boolean, so in this case,  "Hello World" does not equal true.

Just like foo, [] can be evaluated more than one way.  An empty array is still an object; so, in the first case, it coerces to true because it wants to know if [] can be found; however, [] also equals [''].  So now picture this:

```
if (['bar'] == 'bar') ...
```

In this case, JS will not look at ['bar'] to see if it is there, but as an object containing a single value which it can convert to the string, 'bar'.

So:

```
if([]); // is true because it is an object test that evaluates as (1 === 1)
```

and

```
if([] == true) // is false because it is a string test that evaluates as ('' == 1) to (0 === 1)
```

Comment: I don't understand what "response" means in your explanation. There is no such concept in the JavaScript language. `if([])` doesn't check if "you get a response". `if` checks whether the value it gets passed is a `true` or `false`. If the value passed is not a boolean value it is converted to a boolean first.

Comment: an IF statement alway returns true or false meaning IF(<evaluate this as true or false>) {<do this if true>} ELSE{ <do this if false> }; What process an IF statement calls is itself a boolean operation. When you just do an IF statement on a variable/object/etc without any operators such as IF(myVariable){...} Then you are not checking for what myVariable equals, you are checking to see if it exists. In this case [] does exist,but as an empty array, so IF returns true

Comment: I'm confused. First you say that `if` checks true or false, then you say it checks whether "it exists". *"Then you are not checking for what myVariable equals, you are checking to see if it exists."* What is "it"? `if` doesn't check variables it checks values. Variables are just containers for values. Every value "exists". `if(foo)` is the same as `if(Boolean(foo) === true)`. *"In this case [] does exist,but as an empty array, so IF returns true"* It's irrelevant whether the array is empty or not. Every object converted to a Boolean value is `true`, that's why `if([])` is `true`.

Comment: Okay, looked into this further, and yes, if(Boolean(foo) === true) is along the right lines of thinking. The check for existence in most normal use cases looks like if(myVar) and coerces to something along the line of if(1 === 1) or if(0 === 1) which is either a logically true or false statement. So, as you say [] converts down to 1 instead of 0 because it is an object. JS isn't looking for the value of an object because objects can be darn near anything, it's just looking to see if it is there.  So  we are saying the same thing, but from different perspectives I think.

Comment: `[]` converts to `0` when comparing against a boolean. If you are *converting* to a Boolean, then it's not converted to a number but to `true`.

Comment: Booleans in their most basic form are a binary 1 or 0, "true" and "false" are aliases thereof; so, (true === true) evaluates as (1 === 1) because that is how booleans are stored in memory.  As for the converting to a Boolean part, they both convert to a Boolean, but the way they get there is different. Please read my revised answer.  I think my original explanation was confusing because it lacked context; so, hopefully, this clarifies what I've been trying to say.

Comment: *"Booleans in their most basic form are a binary 1 or 0,"* *Any value is a sequence of 1s and 0s, but I'm not talking about implementation details. I'm talking about the JavaScript language specification. Saying that Booleans are just aliases for 1 and 0 is confusing when talking about a dynamically typed language that performs type conversion. At the language level they are not "just" aliases, otherwise `true === 1` would be `true` but it isn't. Specifically I'm talking about this algorithm: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison

Comment: You are answer is still a bit confusing. First of all `document.getElementById("foo") === true` is always `false`, but you are saying *"both of these cases will return true."* which seems to imply that you think it should be `true`, but I'm not sure. *"The issue with [] is that it can be evaluated more than one way."* I get what you want to express, but it still sounds confusing. What happens here is simply type conversion. That happens for *any* object, not just arrays. When using `==` to compare to an object to a primitive value, the object is converted to a primitive value...

Comment: ...how that happens exactly depends on the "type" of object. For arrays that means a concatenating the string representation of each of it's elements. For plain objects it means returning `[object Object]`. All of these are `true`: `[] ==''`, `[''] == ''`, `[] == 0`, `[''] == 0`, `['0'] == 0`, `['0'] == '0'` `[] == false`, `[''] == false`, `['0'] == false`, `[1,2] == '1,2'` `{} == '[object Object]'`, `{foo: 42} == '[object Object]'`.

Comment: *"This makes more since in this case than testing for if (1 == 'bar')"* That's right. `==` will convert both values to a value of the same datatype. However, the *tricky* part is that *both* sides can be converted to different types. And that is what happens when you compare a non-boolean value against a boolean. The Boolean value is converted to a number hence the other value is converted to a number as well.

Comment: If you read ( 7.2.13 Abstract Relational Comparison) from the link you just cited, you will see that IF returns true, false, or NaN.  NaN means that the operators could not be reduced to numbers.  The "return" is not the data type that it is reduced to, it is a new piece of data used by JS to define if the statement results in the THEN operation, the ELSE operation, or an ERROR operation. I use 1 and 0 since we are talking about what what things are actually reduced to which are numbers.

Comment: getElementById does not return as I thought it would, sorry, that was a mis-citation on my part. That seems like a whole other can of worms of JS weirdness probably better left for another question. Knowing that I had that wrong actually makes the existence vs equivalence test make more since. I also re-wrote binary values in a few places to true/false because I tried reading it out loud... and yeah, that was still pretty confusing.  Thanks.

Comment: The comparison algorithm has nothing to do with the `if` statement. The evaluation of the `if` statement is defined in [section 13.6.7](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-if-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation), where you can see in step 2 that the value returned by the condition is converted to a boolean: `Let exprValue be ToBoolean(? GetValue(exprRef)).` Nowhere here is `NaN` mentioned.

Comment: *"If it finds *foo*, then it executes the results in the "then" condition, otherwise you get the "else" condition."* That's not right. What does "finding `foo`" even mean? `foo` is a variable. Variables hold values. If do `var foo;` then `foo` "exists". It doesn't matter which value it has. In `var foo = ''; if (foo) {}`, `foo` exists but `if(foo)` is `false`. Same for `var foo = 0;`, `var foo = false;`, `var foo = null;`, `var foo = NaN;`, etc. I have said before, that `if(x)` is the same as `if(Boolean(x))`. `if` converts *the value* to a Boolean and acts accordingly....

Comment: ... There are different rules for how to convert various values to Boolean values. I believe that you understand what happens, but your way of explaining it is imprecise/misleading.